# DRF - ModelViewSet Create - "This field is required."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following json I'm trying to post -

```
{
    "title": "test",
    "description": "testing desc",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "Welcome1",
    "owner": 4
}
```

The ModelViewSet is below -

```
class PasswordViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Password.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PasswordSerializer
    filter_class = PasswordFilter

    def list(self, request):
        my_passwords = Password.objects.filter(owner=request.user)

        page = self.paginate_queryset(my_passwords)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = PasswordSerializer(my_passwords, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

If I remove the `def list` I can do a post just fine.  The problem is trying to post with that def in there.  it returns that all my fields are required.  Why is it not passing the data?

This is my serializer for reference -

```
class PasswordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Password
```

edit - no idea what's going wrong testing some more here and now it's not even working with the `def list` removed.

model -

```
class Password(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('MyUser', related_name='MyUser_owner')
```

The response is telling me all the fields in the model are required so to me on post the request.data is empty even though the json should be it.

Comment: are u sending the post using jquery or angularjs?

Comment: @whoisearth can you show your models.py and urls.py ?

Comment: plus add the full response from the server so we know what field is causing the error